# Problems with a proof of Hardy's "Introduction to Number Theory"

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, induction

On page 14, in the point **2.2- Further deductions from Euclid's argument.**

I understand all the deductions but at the end he concludes

> $$2^{2+4+\dots+2^{N}}+1<2^{2^{N+1}}.$$

Here, what I think he is doing:

Known that $$2+4+\dots+2^n$$ is a geometric progression, we have $$2^{2+4+\dots+2^{n}} = 2^{2^{n+1}-2}.$$

Now, we compare $2^{2^{n+1}}$ and $2^{2^{n+1}-2}$.

$$2^{2^{n+1}} - 2^{2^{n+1}-2}=2^{2^{n+1}}\dfrac{3}{4}>1$$

hence $2^{2^{n+1}} > 2^{2^{n+1}-2}+1$.

I don't like my method so much. I hope that someone will propose a less artificially way.

Answer (score 1):

As you observe, it's a geometric progression. If you add 1 to it, you get something that sums to $2^{n+1} -1$ ( easy to see  by looking at the binary representation of that number!). If you add $2$ instead, you therefore get $2^{n+1}$.

Now $x \mapsto 2^x$ is an increasing function, so $x^A$ (where $A$ is your sum of powers of $2$) is strictly less than $x^{2^{N+1}}$.